# click on edit outputlink row text show in existing inputField

Tags: inputfield, outputlink

when click on the edit outputlink row text data show in my inputField

[image]

--------------class----------------------

```
public class populationController{
    public List<population__c> stateList{get;set;}
    public population__c statenameobj{get;set;}
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String editlink{get;set;}

    //constructor
    public populationController(){
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        statenameobj = new population__c();
        stateList =new List<population__c>();
        stateList = [SELECT id,State_name__c FROM population__c];
    }

    public void saveas(){

        upsert statenameobj; 
        init();    
    }
    public void editlink(){
        upsert statenameobj;
    }
}
```

-------------------page ----------------------

```
<apex:page controller="populationController" tabStyle="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Insert" action="{!saveas}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter State name for population">
                   <apex:inputField value="{!statenameobj.State_name__c}"/>
                 </apex:pageBlockSection>
                 <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!stateList}" var="st">
                        <apex:column value="{!st.id}" title="Number"/>
                           <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                          <apex:outputLink value=" "> Edit </apex:outputLink> -->

                         </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="State Name" value="{!st.State_name__c }"/>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                 </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript. Populate the value using onClick event.

```
<script>
    function populateValue(newval) {
       document.getElementsByClassName('statename')[0].value=newval;

   }
</script>
<apex:inputField value="{!statenameobj.State_name__c}" styleclass="statename"/>
                 </apex:pageBlockSection>
                 <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!stateList}" var="st">
                        <apex:column value="{!st.id}" title="Number"/>
                           <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                          <apex:outputLink onclick="populateValue('{!st.State_name__c }'); return false;"> Edit </apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: its not working only page reload when click on edit

Comment: @cloudZigZag check my updated code. Make sure you add class name in inputfield as well.

Comment: now value show in inputField but after that page reload and value disappear

Comment: @cloudZigZag try to add` return false;`

Comment: cool, but the thing is why record not updated even i used upsert in my class. like if i click edit of Madhya P and now i'mupdating Madhya Pradesh it not update and create new record. Madhya P already exist and now Madhya Pradesh is also in list neeed to update existing record

Comment: @cloudZigZag that you can post as separate question and refer this question. Also if this solve your problem you can accept this answer.