# value not updating from upsert

Tags: inputfield, upsert, outputlink

when click on edit outputlink text show in inputfield work fine but when save record its create new record instead of updating. how can i update record if id is already exists.

my whole code of class and page is on below link

[click on edit outputlink row text show in existing inputField](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162551/click-on-edit-outputlink-row-text-show-in-existing-inputfield/162554?noredirect=1#comment242390_162554)

class code

```
public class populationController{
public List<population__c> stateList{get;set;}
public population__c statenameobj{get;set;}
public String name{get;set;}
public String editlink{get;set;}

//constructor
public populationController(){
    init();
}

public void init(){
    statenameobj = new population__c();
    stateList =new List<population__c>();
    stateList = [SELECT id,State_name__c FROM population__c];
}

public void saveas(){

    upsert statenameobj; 
    init();    
}
   }
```

Page code

```
    <apex:page controller="populationController" tabStyle="Contact">
<script>
function populateValue(newval) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('statename')[0].value=newval;

   }
</script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Insert" action="{!saveas}"/>  
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter State name for population">
               <apex:inputField value="{!statenameobj.State_name__c}" styleclass="statename"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!stateList}" var="st">
                    <apex:column value="{!st.id}" title="Number"/>
                       <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                      <apex:outputLink onclick="populateValue('{!st.State_name__c }'); return false;"> Edit </apex:outputLink>

                     </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="State Name" value="{!st.State_name__c }"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

             </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Can you post your code here instead of linking to it? Makes life a bit easier. :) Now one reason it would insert instead of update in an upsert is because no Id is specified in your list of objects.

Comment: @cloudZigZag Put the consolidated code because that post has one answer which you've tried.

Comment: I have post class and page code

Answer (score 0):

You don't load `statenameobj` anywhere from the DB (nor do you set an Id or External ID field on the record), so there is nothing to update at the moment of the `upsert` command. Hence, it will insert.

If you wanted to update, you should try to load the record from the DB or set it's ID or and External Id field, so Salesforce can update the record instead of inserting it.